# Unable to automate Reddit using Cypress

Tags: cypress, reddit

Has anyone tried to automate Reddit website using Cypress 10? When I run my tests with "cy.visit('https://www.reddit.com')", my Test Runner just shows up for a moment with Reddit.com loading on the right hand side and immediately closes and then the Specs list is displayed. I can no longer see the Test Run results with Pass/Fail details nor the console. Any help?

I should add that when I use a lower resolution (that of a mobile device) with Reddit website, it works just fine and I can see my test passes. Does Reddit website when viewed on a web browser have elements that Cypress cannot read or access?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The website www.reddit.com does not seem to load as expected in Cypress. When I replace it with www.reddit.com/login it works fine and I can automate it to enter username/password and click on Login, but that's about it. After clicking on Login it just says you will be redirected soon. Whereas when I do the same steps manually, the reddit homepage loads after the login.